# Flyway : interest of creating a SQL init file?

Tags: maven-plugin, database-migration, flyway

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that Flyway's first step to integrate an existing database is to create a SQL init file containing a DDL and reference datas extract from production ([See here](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/DatabaseSetupExisting)). But I don't understand the purpose of such a file since it doesn't seem to be used neither by Flyway's maven plugin nor Flyway's API. So, there is no chance to restore database at its initial state using tools provided by Flyway.
Anyone have an idea about the interest of creating an init file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this is to **align all environments with production**, so you have a common base you can rely on.

The purpose of this is to ensure migrations that'll run against production will have been tried on databases with identical structures in development and test.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but to be more precise, what is the interest in creating a SQL init file whose name matches the name of the base version? For example, while should I create a file named V1.0__base_version.sql before launching `mvn flyway:init -Dflyway.initialVersion=1.0 -Dflyway.initialDescription="base version"` since this file doesn't seem to be exploited by flyway?

Comment: flyway:init is for the production DB to indicate that this is the state as of which Flyway will manage the updates.  V1.0__base_version.sql would then contain this exact structure and be applied to all other environments. This way all environments will have the same structure and Flyway will report 1.0 as being the current version in all of them, even though no migration was executed yet against the production DB. The only thing that happened there was the creation of the metadata table with a single marker row, the result of the init command.

Comment: OK i get it. Thank you and congratulations for your framework !!